# get hands in poker double linked list c++

Tags: list, class, linked-list

I want to deal cards to hands, the amount of hands depend on the amount of players. I have a class deck, which creates a deck, shuffles it, and can remove or insert cards.

Should I make a class for a hand and a class for the list of all the hands? Where should I use the function deal?

Comment: What does this have to do with "double linked list"?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a C++ question, or a question about linked lists, so your question name is misleading.

If I've read your question correctly, this looks like a code structure question. If you are learning this type of material, I'd recommend against using C++, in favour of something easier to prototype; like C# for example.

Here is a C# open source poker game for you to look at. The code architecture looks reasonable:
http://wpfpoker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/48196#172547

I'd suggest you download this and do a code review; then maybe base your own application on it's structure...

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: I need to use c++. It's a school project, so I can't decide which programming language I want to use. I don't know how to accomplish this part of the project.

Comment: and it has to be with double linked lists